# obtain refresh token with no redirect url?

Tags: salesforce1-app, oauth2, authentication

Is there some website I can temporarily use as a redirect url?  I am creating an app that has no web pages and I just need a refresh token so the app can stay connected pretty much forever to sales force and constantly read salesforce data.

I would prefer to just run a curl command and end up with the refresh token that I can use for when my normal token expires but it seems this is not possible.

I am pretty close to giving up and just storing the username/password/client id/client secret in production instead since I can't seem to get a refresh token.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: hmmmm....this would be close but does sales force have something like this.... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-latitude-api/I-tH5pdbYKY

Comment: ah, The Oauth2 supports exactly what I want in the Application Access section of this document http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified#mobile-apps which basically is grant type client_credentials which salesforce does not seem to support?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I figured it out and posted the answer here(that question was before I knew this salesforce forum exists).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642309/how-to-get-a-more-permanent-access-token/22646414#22646414